# Is there a reason why ('iframe').append doesn't work (jQuery)?

Tags: html, jquery

A quickie: In my code
`$("iframe").append(" <b>Appended iframe by element</b>.");` is not being appended.

I also found that  `$("img").append(" <b>Appended p by element</b>.");` also doesn't work.

A fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/stephan_luis/9hqo72ua/8/

jQ select by ID is also tried, both work for a `<p></p>` tag.

My question is why doesn't this work? The docs don't mention anything https://api.jquery.com/append/ Is there a list of html element that jquery methods don't 'do'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery. It is about the HTML you are trying to generate.

`append()` adds child elements to an element.

The children of an `iframe` element in HTML 4.x were alternative content that is only displayed if the browser doesn't support iframes. Today, `iframe` elements aren't allowed children.

Image elements (like iframes) are replaced elements, but they aren't allowed children at all (and never have). `<img><b>Appended p by element</b></img>` is just invalid HTML.

The [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) tells you what content each element is allowed to have in the entry for that element.

e.g. for [iframe](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element) it says:

> Content model:
> Nothing.

Comment: So $("iframe").after(" <b>After iframe by element</b>."); does work, now in the fiddle.

Comment: Works, I mean update the DOM. Somehow didn't pick up the makes new child part from the jQ docs, their version notes separates the 'inserts to the end of each element' from the 'as last child'.

Comment: Could some warning/error in jQ help?  Will use the command line in Chrome from now on to trial functions so can monitor effect on DOM.  Fiddle doesn't show DOM.